# Android: Button in Actionbar is not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbaractivity

I am extending the ActionBarActivity and use fragments in this activity. But the actionbar does not show any button.

Here is my code (inside the fragment):

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_for_edit_fragments, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

And here is the menu_for_edit_fragments.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/item_done"
        android:title="@string/done"
        app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have yo tried testing in other devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call [setHasOptionsMenu(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu%28boolean%29) in [onCreate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) method of the `Fragment`.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` during your fragment `onCreate()`? If you are not, your fragment will not call the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

Hope it helps.